# How to pass the base64string image to url in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I converted my image to base64string but I need to pass the image to my database. How I can covert to URL and render back the encoded image?

Comment: if you have an image converted to base64 you don't need any URL then

Comment: Then how I will send to database?

Comment: Is it in a local or remote database?

Comment: Its in remote database.